# python3 parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have the following xml which contains email configuration for various email service providers, and I'm trying to parse these information into a dict; hostname, is_ssl, port, protocol ..etc

```
<domains>
  <domain>
    <name>zoznam.sk</name>
    <description>Zoznam Slovakia</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>imap.zoznam.sk</hostname>
      <port>143</port>
      <protocol>IMAP</protocol>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>smtp.zoznam.sk</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
    <domain>
    <name>123mail.org</name>
    <description>123mail.org</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>imap.fastmail.com</hostname>
      <port>993</port>
      <protocol>IMAP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <requires/>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>smtp.fastmail.com</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <requires/>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
    <domain>
    <name>Netvigator.com</name>
    <description>netvigator.com</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>corpmail1.netvigator.com</hostname>
      <port>995</port>
      <protocol>POP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <authentication>NONE</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>corpmail1.netvigator.com</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <authentication>NONE</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
</domains>
```

I tried to parse the name for testing but could not succeed, I'm need to python.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


configs_file = 'isp_list.xml'


def parseXML(xmlfile):
    # create element tree object
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)

    # get root element
    root = tree.getroot()

    # create empty list for configs items
    configs = []

    # iterate  items
    for item in root.findall('domains/domain'):
        value = item.get('name')

        # test
        print(value)

        # append news dictionary to items list
        configs.append(item)

    # return items list
    return configs
```

I appreciate your help. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use bs4 to generate a dict.

For the if else lines you could use the more compact syntax of e.g.

```
'ssl' : getattr(item.find('ssl'), 'text', 'N/A')
```

Script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
xml = '''
<domains>
  <domain>
    <name>zoznam.sk</name>
    <description>Zoznam Slovakia</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>imap.zoznam.sk</hostname>
      <port>143</port>
      <protocol>IMAP</protocol>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>smtp.zoznam.sk</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
    <domain>
    <name>123mail.org</name>
    <description>123mail.org</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>imap.fastmail.com</hostname>
      <port>993</port>
      <protocol>IMAP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <requires/>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>smtp.fastmail.com</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <requires/>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
    <domain>
    <name>Netvigator.com</name>
    <description>netvigator.com</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>corpmail1.netvigator.com</hostname>
      <port>995</port>
      <protocol>POP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <authentication>NONE</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>corpmail1.netvigator.com</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <authentication>NONE</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
</domains>

'''

data = {}
soup = bs(xml, 'lxml')

for domain in soup.select('domain'):
    name = domain.select_one('name').text
    data[name] = {
        'name' : name,
        'desc' : domain.select_one('description').text,  
        'services' : {}
    }
    i = 1
    for item in domain.select('service'):
        service = {
                    'hostname' : item.select_one('hostname').text  if item.select_one('hostname') else 'N/A', 
                    'port' : item.select_one('port').text if item.select_one('port') else 'N/A',
                    'protocol' : item.select_one('protocol').text if item.select_one('protocol').text else 'N/A',
                    'ssl' : item.select_one('ssl').text if item.select_one('ssl') else 'N/A',
                    'requires' : item.select_one('requires  \: ').text if item.select_one('requires  \: ') else 'N/A',
                    'authentication' : item.select_one('authentication').text if item.select_one('authentication') else 'N/A',
                    'usernameincludesdomain' : item.select_one('usernameincludesdomain').text if  item.select_one('usernameincludesdomain') else 'N/A'
        }
        data[name]['services'][str(i)] = service
        i+=1
print(data)
```

---

[image]

view the structure [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0923e6521dee4f49b34eb0eecae74269)

---

[image]

---

If you are literally converting xml to a json like structure maybe a library like `untangle` would work?

Comment: Thank you, looks good, however these configs are vary, example; not all configs contains the following       <usernameIncludesDomain/> <ssl/>       <requires/>
I got an error usernameincludesdomain' : item.select_one('usernameincludesdomain').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text

Comment: you can just replicate the if else structure I have used for ssl. I have updated to show.

Comment: Did this fail in some way? I thought you wanted all info?

Comment: could you please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802360/python-parse-specific-text-in-multiple-line

Comment: I didn't downvote your new question but it would be a good idea to include your current code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get names, you can easily use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s='''<domains>
  <domain>
    <name>zoznam.sk</name>
    <description>Zoznam Slovakia</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>imap.zoznam.sk</hostname>
      <port>143</port>
      <protocol>IMAP</protocol>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>smtp.zoznam.sk</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
    <domain>
    <name>123mail.org</name>
    <description>123mail.org</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>imap.fastmail.com</hostname>
      <port>993</port>
      <protocol>IMAP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <requires/>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>smtp.fastmail.com</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <requires/>
      <authentication>PLAIN</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
    <domain>
    <name>Netvigator.com</name>
    <description>netvigator.com</description>
    <service>
      <hostname>corpmail1.netvigator.com</hostname>
      <port>995</port>
      <protocol>POP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <authentication>NONE</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <hostname>corpmail1.netvigator.com</hostname>
      <port>587</port>
      <protocol>SMTP</protocol>
      <ssl/>
      <authentication>NONE</authentication>
      <usernameIncludesDomain/>
    </service>
  </domain>
</domains>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

configs = [n.text for n in soup.find_all('name')]
```

and you get:

```
['zoznam.sk', '123mail.org', 'Netvigator.com']
```

---

To get information for each service, you can add this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

configs = {}

services = soup.find_all('service')

for serv in services:
    hostname = serv.find('hostname').text
    configs[hostname] = {}
    configs[hostname]['port'] = serv.find('port').text
    configs[hostname]['protocol'] = serv.find('protocol').text
    configs[hostname]['auth'] = serv.find('authentication').text
```

and you get `configs` which is a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
{'imap.zoznam.sk': {'port': '143', 'protocol': 'IMAP', 'auth': 'PLAIN'},
 'smtp.zoznam.sk': {'port': '587', 'protocol': 'SMTP', 'auth': 'PLAIN'},
 'imap.fastmail.com': {'port': '993', 'protocol': 'IMAP', 'auth': 'PLAIN'},
 'smtp.fastmail.com': {'port': '587', 'protocol': 'SMTP', 'auth': 'PLAIN'},
 'corpmail1.netvigator.com': {'port': '587', 'protocol': 'SMTP', 'auth': 'NONE'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to get all information, I used name in the question just for testing that parsing succeed

Comment: Ok, so do you want to get information for each service, don't you?

Comment: yes that is correct, I need to get config information for each service.

Comment: but how to parse <usernameIncludesDomain/> and  <requires/> <ssl/> ?

Comment: I do not know, I found these configs on a website.

Comment: You will get nothing from those tags.