# Parse specific text in multiple line

Tags: python

I have a text file contain a sample data like this:

```
[|] Name: Foo Bar
[|] Username: xx@example.org
[|] NickName: Boox AA
[|] Logo Box: Unique-w.jpg
[|] Country: EU
=========================================
[|] Name: Doo Mar
[|] Username: cc@example.net
[|] Logo Box: Unique-w.jpg
[|] Country: EU
[|] Mob: 00000000
```

I need to get `Username` and `Logo Box` values

I tried using for loop to get 2 lines each time and analyze it but it does not work as expected:

```
def read_file_lines(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as fp:
        return fp.readlines()

lines = read_file_lines('data.txt')

result = {}
index = 1
for line in lines:
    if 'Username:' in line:
        result[index] = {}
        result[index]['username'] = line # cleanup
    elif 'Logo Box:' in line:
        result[index]['LogoBox'] = line  # cleanup
    index += 1
```

example valid solution output would be:

```
result = {
'1': {'username': 'xx@example.org', 'LogoBox': 'Unique-w.jpg'}
}
```

Comment: please include your current code. Is this coming from a text file?

Comment: yes, from a text file

Comment: I have added my code, I know it's terrible

Comment: What is the actual output you're getting? Your code looks to me like it should work, except that you never increment `index`. Perhaps that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this code below:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ':' in line:
            k, v = line.split(':')
            if 'Username' in k:
                print('Username:', v)
            elif 'Logo Box' in k:
                print('Logo Box:', v)
```

output:

```
Username:  xx@example.org

Logo Box:  Unique-w.jpg

Username:  cc@example.net

Logo Box:  Unique-w.jpg
```

Comment: This is not efficient solution

Comment: @Manix , you said you need to get both `Username` and `Logo Box` and you can see them in the output printed out, please explain what is not efficient?!